# How to stop my pivot table created from data model from bringing in all data (not just matched data from lookup)?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have created a data model, connecting several tables via related columns.

For example, I have connected the '[Mod Code]' column from one table and 'ProvisionCode' from another table, as these two columns are equivalent types of data from each table so wanted to use them as the lookup column to match data.  Basically, my objective is to do a lookup between the two tables and pull through related data.

The problem is that when i try to make a Pivot Table from the data model and bring in the 'Provision Code' related to 'Mod Code', I get all 'Provision Codes', not just the ones related to 'Mod Code' via the connection.

**Showing the Connections and the Pivot Table ouput**

[image: Image: Showing the Connections and the Pivot Table ouput]

Is there something I am doing wrong?

I was expecting that when I pulled through the 'Provision Codes' related to 'mod code' , I should see the exact same 'Provision Code' because that is what i am matching with the connection, but I am getting all 'Provision Code' being pulled through including 'Provision Codes' that do not match the 'Mod Code' (see the image above)